# problem with printer

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, canon

I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS installed on my computer.
I try to install printers HP Laser Jet 1020 and Canon MF 3010 and Lexmark x1180 all in one with scanner.

I do everything correct and installation of HP 1020 and Canon MF 3010 are all right. When I command to print something I notice that printer tray work but nothing is printing. When I command to print test page it answer that print page is printing, but nothing is coming out of printer.
Lexmark x1180 doesn't work because I can't find any properly installation.
Can you explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

This is always the best driver I had ever use to print with cups: http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php

In a couple of occasion this driver works better then driver provided from vendor.